# Use an external container registry with GitLab as an auth endpoint

Tags: docker-registry, gitlab-ce

I have a gitlab-ce (13.10.2 installed from omnibus on ubuntu 20.10) and a external docker registry (2.7.1 running as a docker container on this machine). This installation is set to run and resolve DNS locally on this machine and basically all works fine.

I tried to configure the gitlab auth (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#use-an-external-container-registry-with-gitlab-as-an-auth-endpoint) between gitlab and the container registry.

My docker-compose.yaml : https://pastebin.com/SptXzuSC
My gitlab.rb: https://pastebin.com/jVxKCWYs

My problem is now when I run `docker login registry.example.com`. I'm asked to fill username and password. **I fill the gitlab username and the token but Its returns an error "401 unauthorized".**

I followed the troubleshooting advises https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#docker-login-attempt-fails-with-token-signed-by-untrusted-key But I have always the same error 401.

If someone has an idea to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.